# Change string encoded in win1250 to utf8

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, iconv

I'm loading a file that has encoding win1250, but when I load it, it has characters like `p��jemce` instead of `příjemce` (note diacritics.)

I'd like to change the encoding FROM win1250 TO UTF8.

I managed to do it in PHP with the following code

`$content = iconv('windows-1250', 'UTF-8', $content);`

but I am unable to do it in Javascript. I need to do this encoding on client without sending it to server (so I can't use PHP as "encoding proxy")

I've tried to use libraries `iconv-lite` and `text-encoding` (on NPM) like this

```
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = () => {
      var data = reader.result;
      // iconv-lite
      var buf = iconv.encode(data, 'win1250');
      var str1 = iconv.decode(new Buffer(buf), 'utf8');

      // text-encoding
      var uint8array = new TextEncoder('windows-1250').encode(data);
      var str2 = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(uint8array);

      console.log(str1);
      console.log(str2);
    };

    reader.readAsText(file);
```

But neither has actually correctly changed the encoding. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Have you not got encode/decode the wrong way around? From your question it sounds like you're trying to decode a file in win1250, and treat it as utf-8?

Comment: Yes, I do have a file that is in win1250 and I want it to be utf8. Thing is, it is "encoding" from string to bytes and "decoding" from bytes to string. More at https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could simply try `reader.readAsArrayBuffer`

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = () => {
  var buf = reader.result;
  // iconv-lite
  var str1 = iconv.decode(buf, 'win1250');

  // text-encoding
  var str2 = new TextDecoder('windows-1250').decode(buf);

  console.log(str1);
  console.log(str2);
};

reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

If `readAsArrayBuffer` should get the binary data directly.

I don't have the entire dev environment so the above code is not fully tested, hope it could at least be inspirational.

Comment: Thank you very much! I havent read much about encoding, that's why I was trying to first encode it from win1250 to bytes and then decode it from bytes to utf8. That's obviously not the way to do it. Saved me a lot of time!